# How could I substring an NSString to the third occurrence of a character?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

I want to count the ',' characters and substring when it has been repeated 3 times.

Input:

```
9,1,2,3,9
```

Output:

```
9,1,2
```

Comment: Please clarify. Your input and desired result is just confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure something that specific would not have a build in method.
Off the top of my head:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i)
{
    if([string characterAtIndex:i] == ',')
    {
         ++commaCount;
         if(commaCount == 3)
         {
              return [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, i)];
         }
     }
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

The apple reference documents are usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourString substringFromIndex:[yourString rangeOfString:@","].location]
```

Something like that.

Comment: Look at NSString and NSRange... both of those should help you.

Comment: Didn't think of that, the rangeOfString:option:range method could be used for the requirement of being the third occurrence.

Comment: Hmmm... actually the problem with the above is that it only finds the first.  rangeOfString:option:range may not be as useful either.  So actually I think your solution is better :-)

Comment: You could do a loop 3 times each time changing the range to find the third element and then substring. It would probably be harder to understand than my solution.