# occurrence of a character in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am googling NSSting manipulation methods from last few hours. and found many on stack overflow like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504115/how-could-i-substring-an-nsstring-to-the-third-occurrence-of-a-character)

I have a String **"1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA"**. String may have any number of "," . I have to take the third last(San Franncisco) and last(USA) substring after ",".

and output should be "**San Franncisco USA**".

I have logic how to do this in my mind that but I am struggling to implement it.

I try this code for getting the position of last three "," in string. but it's not work for me

```
 NSInteger commaArr[3];

        int index=0;   
        int commaCount=0;

        for(unsigned int  i =  [strGetCityName length]; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if([strGetCityName characterAtIndex:i] == ',')
            {

                commaArr[index]=i;
                index++;
                ++commaCount;
                if(commaCount == 3)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSString *s = @"1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA";
NSArray *parts = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSUInteger len = [parts count];
NSString *res;
if (len >= 3) {
    res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [parts objectAtIndex:len-3], [parts objectAtIndex:len-1]];
} else {
    res = @"ERROR: Not enough parts!";
}
```

The `componentsSeparatedByString:` will split the string at `,`, and `stringWithFormat:` will put the parts back together.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *s = @"1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(?:[^,]*,)?\\s*([^,]*),\\s*(?:[^,]*),\\s*([^,]*)$" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *result = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:s options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length]) withTemplate:@"'$1 $2'"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *string = @"1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA";
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *sanFrancisco = [components objectAtIndex:components.count - 3];
NSString *usa = [components objectAtIndex:components.count - 1];
NSString *result = [sanFrancisco stringByAppendingString:usa];
```