# How to delete string after third comma ( , ) from string in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am getting a string from web service like:
    @"current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool, Dattavadi, Pune, Maharashtra         411030, India".
    Now i want remove string after third comma so address will look like:
   @"current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool, Dattavadi";
   and remove third comma.
   Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What did you try? Will it always have commas?

Comment: yes, because address is coming from google api.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` could be a way. `componentsSeparatedByString`, with a reconstruction after could be another way. What did you try?

Comment: This post will help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504115/how-could-i-substring-an-nsstring-to-the-third-occurrence-of-a-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `componentsSeparatedByString`:

```
NSString *list = @"current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool, Dattavadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411030, India";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

// produces an array { @"Karin", @"Carrie", @"David"" }.
```

// here check if listItems.count >=3

```
NSString* reducedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",[listItems objectAtIndex:0],[listItems objectAtIndex:1],[listItems objectAtIndex:2] ];
```

Comment: Better than the other answer, but `componentsJoinedByString` is better than manually recreating the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using basic [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) methods.

I just wrote a method that does exactly what you are asking:

```
-(NSString *) clearStringAfterThirdComma: (NSString *) originalString {

    NSMutableString *clearedString = [originalString mutableCopy];

    NSInteger commaCount = 0;

    // iterate thru each character of the string

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < originalString.length; i++) {

        NSString *subString = [originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        if ([subString isEqualToString:@","]) {

            commaCount++;

            if (commaCount == 3) {
                [clearedString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, originalString.length - i)];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return clearedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but it's bothering me, so here's my solution;

Here's the method:

```
- (NSString *)shortenedAddress:(NSString *)address {
    // Turn the string into an array of each part separated by a comma
    NSArray *components = [address componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    // No need to shorten the address if there are three items or less
    if ([components count] < 4) {
        return address;
    }

    // Create a range object for the first three items in the array
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 3;

    return [[components subarrayWithRange:range] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
```

And if you test it with this:

```
NSString *fullAddress = @"current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool, Dattavadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411030, India"; // More than three items
NSString *partialAddress = @"current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool"; // Less than three items

NSLog(@"Full Address: %@", [self shortenedAddress:fullAddress]);
NSLog(@"Partial Address: %@", [self shortenedAddress:partialAddress]);
```

it gives the following output in the console:

> `Full Address: current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool, Dattavadi`
>
> `Partial Address: current address is Narveer Tanaji Malusare Road, Dandekar Pool`

I think it's shorter, easier to understand, and easier to modify than the accepted answer, but that's just my opinion.